# Tkinter <Return> function not working

Tags: python, tkinter, return, bind

I've read so many other answers to such questions, but they **don't** work...So **please** don't mark it ***duplicate***...
I'm a Python self-learner, running on Windows on  in Python 3.6.
This is the code-

```
self.btnCalc = Button(self, text = "Calculate", command=self.calculate, bd=10)
self.btnCalc.grid(row = 11, column = 5)
self.btnCalc.bind('<Return>', self.calculate)
```

[This is the link](https://gist.github.com/gaya3p/2cee9651cd20fff1ea8fd093fdd330cb) to the whole code (to calculate school grades).

Comment: What doesn't work? You haven't actually said.

Comment: The button doesn't get executed when i press enter key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to trigger the command without clicking the button, so you need to bind the event to your main widget, `self`.

You don't bind the event to the button command, but to the command directly. When you create a binding on a parent, it's available to all children widgets, Entry...

you can use this :

```
self.bind('<Return>', self.calculate) 
# or self.bind('<KP_Enter>', self.calculate) to trigger numpad Return
```

But your method `calculate` must have a parameter for event, even if you don't use it :

```
def calculate(self, event=None):
```

**Explanation about *event* :**

When you bind a function to an event with the method `widget.bind(...)`, tkinter calls the function with **one** parameter : the event. It contains informations about the action triggered, like the coordinates of mouse, or any relevant detail to handle the event correctly.

You don't use it in your function (yet ?), but you need to declare it.

Then, as you are using the function from the button AND from the binding, it has to be declared as an *optional parameter*, with a default value : `None`, because the command inside a button doesn't generate this `event` parameter when it calls the function.

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: Nah in tkinter you just need to bind <Return> no need for the key- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm but you were right about calculate not having an `event` parameter

Comment: But when I now mannually (with mouse) press the button, it shows-`Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: calculate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'`

Comment: Yes, fixed in answer, indeed,  if you are using the function from the button, `event` is not given... so a default parameter is needed here

Comment: How to code so that `Enter` key and manually pressing it would work?

Comment: you can use `def calculate(self, event=None)` instead of my first code suggestion

Comment: you're welcome! i've just added some explanations about this event parameter